# Python automated file names

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7

I want to automate the file name used when saving a spreadsheet using `xlwt`. Say there is a sub directory named `Data` in the folder the python program is running. I want the program to count the number of files in that folder (# = n). Then the filename must end in (n+1). If there are 0 files in the folder, the filename must be `Trial_1.xls`. This file must be saved in that sub directory.

I know the following:

```
import xlwt, os, os.path
n = len([name for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(name)])
```

counts the number of files in the same folder.

```
a = n + 1
filename = "Trial_" + "a" + ".xls"
book.save(filename)
```

this will save the file properly named in to the same folder.

My question is how do I extend this in to a sub directory? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.listdir('.')` the `.` in this points to the directory from where the file is executed. Change the `.` to point to the subdirectory you are interested in.

You should give it the full path name from the root of your file system; otherwise it will be relative to the directory from where the script is executed. This might not be what you want; especially if you need to refer to the sub directory from another program.

You also need to provide the full path to the `filename` variable; which would include the sub directory.

To make life easier, just set the full path to a variable and refer to it when needed.

```
TARGET_DIR = '/home/me/projects/data/'
n = sum(1 for f in os.listdir(TARGET_DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(TARGET_DIR, f)))
new_name = "{}Trial_{}.xls".format(TARGET_DIR,n+1)
```

Comment: `os.listdir` does not give a full path. Only the base names.

Comment: Yep, fixed and made it a bit better without the comprehension.

Comment: Works perfectly! I used TARGET_DIR = 'data/' since it's in the same folder (I think I was unclear in my original question). Thanks. Also, I noticed the way you created the filename is much more efficient with .format(). How do you use that? Never seen it before.

Comment: See the documentation on [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 3):

You actually want [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#module-glob):

```
from glob import glob    

DIR = 'some/where/'
existing_files = glob(DIR + '*.xls')
filename = DIR + 'stuff--%d--stuff.xls' % (len(existing_files) + 1)
```

Comment: This is far more appropriate than doing an `os.listdir` because glob immediately resolves your files from the extension pattern. I would however recommend using `os.glob1(DIR, '*.xls')` to make the result list much smaller (only basenames), and using `os.path.join` for joining the DIR and new basename.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said Burhan Khalid's answer "Works perfectly!" you should accept it.

I just wanted to point out a different way to compute the number.  The way you are doing it works, but if we imagine you were counting grains of sand or something would use way too much memory.  Here is a more direct way to get the count:

```
n = sum(1 for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(name))
```

For every qualifying name, we get a 1, and all these 1's get fed into `sum()` and you get your count.

Note that this code uses a "generator expression" instead of a list comprehension.  Instead of building a list, taking its length, and then discarding the list, the above code just makes an iterator that `sum()` iterates to compute the count.

It's a bit sleazy, but there is a shortcut we can use: `sum()` will accept boolean values, and will treat `True` as a 1, and `False` as a 0.  We can sum these.

```
# sum will treat Boolean True as a 1, False as a 0
n = sum(os.path.isfile(name) for name in os.listdir('.'))
```

This is sufficiently tricky that I probably would not use this without putting a comment.  But I believe this is the fastest, most efficient way to count things in Python.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize there was an "Accept" feature; I'm new to this site. Done :)

Comment: @Jey you should read the [how to ask questions FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).